# there aren't any apples/any apples aren't

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

I read on a webpage that we can use this sentence :

> An apple is in the fridge

instead of this one:

> There is an apple in the fridge.

I wonder what can we say instead of this sentence:

> There aren't any apples in the fridge

My guesses are two following sentences. Which one is correct, and why?

1. Any apples are in the fridge
2. Apples aren't in the fridge

Comment: You might want to consider "no apples are in the fridge" among your options.

Comment: Any is for questions and negations. Not for declaratives.

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples are unusual but possible in certain contexts, and really only as responses to something that someone else has asked or said. For example:

> A: Do you have any apples to go with my salad?
> B: (I'm not sure.) Any apples are in the fridge. (Go take a look!)

meaning: **Any apples that we might have are kept in the fridge.**

and

> A: I've looked in the fridge and I can't find the apples.
> B: Apples aren't in the fridge. (You'll find them in the basket on the table.)

meaning: **Apples aren't kept in the fridge.**

Answer (score 0):

"Any apples in the fridge" is not grammatical. "Any" is a [negative-polarity item](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Negative_polarity_item) and can only be used in a negative clause or a question. For example:

> I don't want any apples 
> Do you have any apples?

"Apples aren't in the fridge" is grammatical. But I believe that the definite subject is pragmatically more likely:

> The apples aren't in the fridge